# JavaScript - Find out how many times a number goes into another number evenly

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to find how many times a number goes into another number evenly in JavaScript?

Say 11 divided by 4 --- I know 4 goes into 11 2 times evenly

I have this code but I thought there was a simpler way that I maybe forgetting?

```
<script>
a = 11;
b = 4;

i = a % b;
i2 = a - i;
solution = i2 / b;
document.write(solution); // 2
</script>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What about...

```
Math.floor(11 / 4);
```

If you're wanting to handle negative numbers (thanks [Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp)), you could use `~~`, `|0` or any other bitwise trick that will treat its operand as a 32 bit signed integer. Keep in mind, besides this being confusing, it won't handle a number over 32bits.

```
~~(11 / 4);
```

Comment: `Math.floor` is not the right tool if there's a chance that the quotient is negative.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this trick:

```
(a / b) >> 0
```

Shifting by 0 truncates the fractional part. This will always round toward 0, which `Math.floor` will not do with negative numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't using *any* bitwise operator truncate the fractional portion?   (not my downvote)

Comment: @alex - Pretty much. Your suggestion for using `~~` works fine. I'd rather do one bitwise operation rather than two, is all. :) -- Ah! I just saw that you also suggested `|0`. That's tied with my trick for simplicity!

Comment: I gave you an upvote for the tip. I've never programmed through front panel switches, but it sounds interesting, would love to have a beer but I believe we might live in different continents.

Comment: @alex - +1 to you, too. The next time I hoist a cold one I'll wave it towards you. I'll have to wave it toward my feet, I guess!

Comment: Interesting. I prefer Math.floor(11 / 4); but like this as it does negatives.